# How can I select row or rows or cell in Infragistic UltraGrid?

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I need to select one row, multiple rows or a cell in Ultragrid to copy from the grid. How can this be accomplish?

Comment: Are you trying to select certain rows programatically or are do you want the user to be able to select multiple rows and cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very specific, but if you want to get or set the selected row, you can use the .Selected property on the row. You can also use:

```
_yourGrid.DisplayLayout.ActiveRow = whateverRowYouWantSelected
```

For multiple selection, you can use

```
_yourGrid.DisplayLayout.SelectedRows
```

Comment: _yourGrid.DisplayLayout.ActiveRow : I've just tried this but it seems this is a read only prop for me.

Comment: @Jens _yourGrid.ActiveRow does work, maybe this changed since 2009. see my answer for working example

Answer (score 1):

select the "Feature Picker" of ultragrid designer dialog and expand the "Selection" node.
you should be able to configure the cell, row, column selection the way that you want. Also you can enable either single or multiple rows selection.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example on how we can Filter a row by the value of a property of its list object.

```
var rowToSelect = _texteViewModelsUltraGrid.Rows.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ListObject is TexteSetViewModel txtvm 
                                                                  && txtvm.Category == "MyCategory");
if (rowToSelect != null)
    _texteViewModelsUltraGrid.ActiveRow = rowToSelect;
```

In this case we will select the first row where the underlying list object, a viewmodel holding information about a text, is of category MyCategory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really open ended question (web/win forms?). The best advice I can give you is if you open up the UltraWinGrid Designer from the grid's smart tag, then select the "Feature Picker" and expand the "Selection" node you should be able to configure the cell, row, column selection the way that you want.

I hope that helps.